# Convert a 1 row (comma separated) text file to multiple rows

Tags: windows, command-line, sed, awk, text-formatting

How can I convert text files with the following format:

```
["word01","word02","word03","word04","word05","word06","word07","word08","word09"]
```

to the following format:

```
word01
word02
word03 
word04 
word05 
word06 
word07 
word08 
word09
```

I use windows, and I want to do it from a .bat file
I have read about SED, AWK commands, but have not been able to achieve it.

Comment: cat filecontainingdata |sed 's/","/\n/g'  try that.  However you will still have to remove the { and ] separately.  In windows replace **cat** with **type**